# Gulp-livereload обновляет страницу только один раз

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm

При настройке gulp и плагина gulp-livereload стили на сайте обновляются только 1 раз. При чем нет ошибок ни в браузере, не в консоли. Расширение к chrome ("LiveReload") подключено к серверу и никаких ошибок не выдает. В чем может быть проблема? Ниже приведу код файла gulpfile.js и скрин консоли.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
less = require('gulp-less'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('less', function() {
gulp.src('./public/css/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./public/css/*.less', gulp.series('less'));
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
.pipe(livereload({ start: true }));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь дать более развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать прямо так, как указано в документации gull-livereload:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./public/css/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

Comment: Как я понял, в gulp версии 4 так уже не получиться написать. У меня на примере с документации всегда была ошибка.